# Trying to find the name of this anime about powers, school, rank and bullies

Tags: story-identification, anime

Ok so I can’t remember the name and I’ve been trying to look everywhere. Here’s what I remember:

The main character is a boy, who befriends a girl. This girl happens to be one of the top kids at the school that has ranks based on how strong your powers are and if you have any at all. He wanted to forget his past because it turns out he is super strong and violent, but he enters this school as if he doesn’t have any powers at all.

He ends up getting bullied and learns to defend himself without using any powers at all. Eventually he ends up slowly taking out the top kids because of the bullying but is using a disguise so no one will know that it’s him.

He can mimic the power of whoever uses there powers near him.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site, could you recall any more details such as when you saw this? I'd highly recommend looking at this [post](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) that will help you see what details we find useful to include to help us help you :D If you haven't already, you might find it useful to read what's in the [help] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That sounds a lot like the webtoon [unOrdinary](https://www.webtoons.com/en/super-hero/unordinary/list?title_no=679&page=1):

> Nobody paid much attention to John – just a normal teenager at a high school where the social elite happen to possess unthinkable powers and abilities. But John’s got a secret past that threatens to bring down the school’s whole social order – and much more. Fulfilling his destiny won’t be easy though, because there are battles, frenemies and deadly conspiracies around every corner.

It matches every recollection you have (John can copy powers, he was very violent at his previous school, he befriends a top ranked girl, etc). Of course, it's a webtoon, not an anime.

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhh !!! Man well I guess that’s how good it is. My imagination went off on the webtoon and I guess I pictured it that vividly that I thought it was an anime !!!! That’s right ! I used to read on webtoon a lot ! Thank you!